# calculating exp(3.8) without import

Tags: python, python-3.x, exponential

is there a way to make a code to calculate the exp(3.8) without using any import whether it's math or any other imports.

I wanna try making a program that calculates the exp of any number without using imports but I can't figure it out so does anyone have any proposition on where I should start or an example of a code.

Comment: Why not use imports? And you could just look up the algorithm to compute what you want, then write that code yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, remember e is just a number!

```
e = 2.718281828459045
e ** 3.8
>> 44.70118449330081
```

Comment: If you are interested in computing it to an arbitrary number of dp then [this](https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/Math/Math-e.php) is a place to start.

Answer (score -1):

The operator "**" is used to exponential.

Example bellow:

```
>>> 4**2
>>> 16
```

Comment: Don't think this is what he was asking for, see BenedictWilkinsAI's solution.